# Myriad Pro doesn't have bold anymore?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

Few years ago I remember using Myriad Pro in Illustrator. That font was complete with both bold and italic forms.

In my latest Illustrator, I only have the `normal` form. Is Myriad Pro different from the one I used to use?

Comment: This  looks like problem with a program. You can easily check if Illsutrator installed Adobe fonts on your computer.

Comment: I have 10 variations of Myriad Pro in my Mac El Capitan. Illustrator CC 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe might change what they include in every update of their apps. Also, we can't possibly know what's happening inside your machine, which may affect the list of available fonts in AI.

To see what the 'Myriad Pro' family actually includes when purchased indedepently, go to:

- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/myriad/

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Adobe CC account, you can open your CC desktop app, click on "Fonts" to go to the Adobe Font site, and there you can sync the other versions of the font to your computer.  There are 40 varieties of Myriad Pro available to choose from (at no extra cost).